# Laravel doble factor de autenticación

Tags: laravel, autenticación

Estoy intentando implementar un sistema de login con doble autenticación, de modo que, cuando el usuario introduce sus credenciales correctas se le envía un correo electrónico con un código generado por el paquete Google2FA. Entonces se pasa a una vista donde el usuario debe teclear el código que le ha llegado por mail para completar la autenticación. El método login me queda así:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{

    $this->validateLogin($request);

    if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    $user = User::where($this->username(), '=', $request->email)->first();

    if (password_verify($request->password, optional($user)->password)) {
        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
        $key = (new Google2FA)->generateSecretKey();
        $user->token_login = $key;
        $user->save();
        Mail::send(new Code2fa(
            [
                'email' => $user->email,
                'name' => $user->name,
                'code' => $key,
            ]
        ));
        return view("auth.confirmation")->with(['user' => $user]);
    }

    $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}
```

Hasta aquí, sin problemas. El mail se envía correctamente, y salta a la vista `auth.confirmation`, donde aparece un campo de texto para introducir el código que se ha recibido por mail. La vista es la siguiente:

```
@extends ('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="alert alert-warning">
            Introduzca el código que se le ha enviado por correo, para confirmar el acceso.
        </div>
        <form action="{{ route ('confirm2fa', $user) }}" method="post">
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="typed_code">Código de confirmación de acceso</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('typed_code') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" id="typed_code" name="typed_code" value="{{ old('typed_code') }}" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Enviar">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Esta vista envía el formulario por post a una ruta adicional, para verificar el código. La ruta es la siguiente:

```
Route::namespace('Auth')->group(function () {
    Route::post('/access_confirm/{user}', 'LoginController@confirm2fa')->name('confirm2fa');
});
```

Hasta aquí, también sin problemas. El formulario se enruta correctamente hasta el método controlador indicado. El código del controlador es el siguiente:

```
public function confirm2fa(Request $request, User $user)
{
    $reglas = [
        'typed_code' => 'exists:users,token_login,id,'.$user->id,
    ];
    $mensajes = [
        'typed_code.exists' => 'Código de verificación incorrecto',
    ];
    $request->validate($reglas, $mensajes);

    $request->session()->regenerate();
    Auth::login($user);
    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Y aquí aparecen los problemas. En primer lugar, la validación no actúa como debe. Si el código de confirmación no coincide con el enviado por mail, se redirige a la vista de login, en lugar de dirigirse al formulario donde se pide el código de confirmación, para mostrar el error, como debería hacer.
Por otro lado, si el código de confirmación es correcto, se lanza una excepción: `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Auth' not found`.

Creo que todo el problema pueda surgir del método `confirm2fa()`, pero no veo porque estos dos fallos. He revisado la documentación, y esto debería funcionar, pero no lo hace.

Comment: Has intentado con `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`? La redirección depende de tu `Middleware`, lo más probable es que estés redirigiendo al login.

Comment: Esa inclusión la tengo al principio del controlador, junto con las demás instrucciones use. Sin embargo, sigue sin hacer la validación correctamente.

Comment: Has intentado hacer esto? https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/apphttpcontrollersauthauth-not-found-in-laravel-56

Comment: También como consejo, deberías poner qué versión de laravel estás usando

Comment: Hola. Estoy usando laravel 5.8, que entra dentro de lo razonable. No es la última, pero aun así no debería fallar el validate.

Comment: Si ya has intentado esas dos cosas que te dije y no ha funcionado, podrías poner `use Auth;` en vez de los otros

Comment: Si, con eso la autenticación ya funciona, cuando se teclea el código de verificación correcto. El problema es que, cuando se teclea un código incorrecto, no hace la validación para volver a pedir el código. Salta directamente a la vista de login, pero sin dar ninguna explicación.